# 64 bits ant.jar

Tags: java, ant, 64-bit, jvm

I have installed 64 bits RHEL. I have following questions regarding ant.jar for the system.

1. I was not able to find ant.jar build with 64 bit JVM from the apache website. Do I have to build it form the source code, if I intend to run the jar on 64 bit JVM?
2. Would it speed up the build process if I use ant.jar build with 64 bit JVM and run it on 64 bit JVM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a special 64 bit build of a pure Java application such as Ant.  The `ant.jar` will run equally on a 32 bit or 64 bit JVM.

The only cases where you would definitely need to run a 64 bit version of a Java application are:

- when the application includes native code libraries; i.e. the application is not pure Java, or
- when the Java application has been compiled directly to native code; e.g. using `gcj`.

(It is possible that a poorly written application will be operating system dependent.  For example, someone could hard code an application to use OS-specific line separators or pathnames, or to rely on specific OS-specific external commands.  But the chances are that even this won't make the application dependent on the OS memory model.)

Answer (score 1):

No, java bytecode is java bytecode, it doesn't matter whether it was built with a 32-bit or 64-bit JDK.

For the same reason, it doesn't matter which operating system it was built on either. For example: a jar built with a 32-bit JDK on 32-bit Microsoft Windows should run just fine on a 64-bit JRE on 64-bit RHEL.

Comment: Do you mean to say that any java source code when compiled using 32 bit JDK would run 64 bit JRE?